# python monitor a log file non blocking

Tags: python, logging, generator, tail

I have a test stub that will write several log messages to the system log.

But, this system log gets updated by many other applications as well. So, basically, I want to do a `tail -f system.log | grep "application name"` to get only the appropriate log messages.

I was looking at dbaez generator tricks, and I am trying to combine the both http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/follow.py and http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/apachelog.py

So, in my `__main__()`, I have something like this:

```
try:
   dosomeprocessing()     #outputs stuff to the log file
```

And within dosomeprocessing(), I run a loop, and for each loop, I want to see if there are any new log messages caused by my application, and not necessarily print it out, but store them somewhere to do some validation.

```
    logfile = open("/var/adm/messages","r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    logpats = r'I2G(JV)'
    logpat = re.compile(logpats)
    groups = (logpat.match(line) for line in loglines)
    for g in groups:
        if g:
            print g.groups()
```

The log looks something like :

```
Feb  4 12:55:27 Someprocessname.py I2G(JV)-300[20448]: [ID 702911   local2.error] [MSG-70047] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
 Feb  4 12:55:27 Someprocessname.py I2G(JV)-300[20448]: [ID 702911  local2.error] [MSG-70055] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

in addition to a lot of other gobblygook.

Right now, it gets stuck in the for g in groups:

I am relatively new to python and asynchronous programming. Ideally, I would like to be able to have the tail running parallely to the main process, and read new data with each loop.

Please let me know if I need to add more information.

Comment: Did the log file rotate? Your `follow.py` doesn't handle a logger that renames `messages` to, say, `messages.1` then creates a new file for additional logs.

Comment: It almost never rotates, the filename remains the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use either [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) or [pyinotify](http://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki) to monitor changes to your log file.

Also, I would suggest to remember last position you read from. After you get IN_MODIFY notification, you could read from last position to the end of file and apply your loop again. Also, reset last position to 0 when it is bigger than size of file in case file was truncated.

Here is example:

```
import pyinotify
import re
import os


wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
mask = pyinotify.IN_MODIFY


class EventHandler (pyinotify.ProcessEvent):

    def __init__(self, file_path, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.file_path = file_path
        self._last_position = 0
        logpats = r'I2G\(JV\)'
        self._logpat = re.compile(logpats)

    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):
        print "File changed: ", event.pathname
        if self._last_position > os.path.getsize(self.file_path):
            self._last_position = 0
        with open(self.file_path) as f:
            f.seek(self._last_position)
            loglines = f.readlines()
            self._last_position = f.tell()
            groups = (self._logpat.search(line.strip()) for line in loglines)
            for g in groups:
                if g:
                    print g.string


handler = EventHandler('some_log.log')
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)

wm.add_watch(handler.file_path, mask)        
notifier.loop()
```

Comment: I didn't use pyinotify, but instead used the file read, file seek methods you defined above to do it. Thanks!